# Just moved DNN installation to dev server, now all sub-pages are 404

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I just migrated my localhost installation of DNN over to an internal development server. I have everything setup as on local (permissions, app pool, etc.).

The home page on the dev server pulls up just fine, so I know I have access to the db, but when I navigate to any sub-pages (admin included), they're all 404.

Is there something I have missed in the migration process? Thanks in advance!

DNN v7.02.02,
IIS Local - v7.5,
IIS Dev - v7.0

Here's an example of the url:

Working on local server: localhost/dnn/support

Not working (even though alias was added) on dev server: 10.0.201.XX/dnn/support

UPDATE: I tried a clean DNN install on the same dev server, and the same thing happened!

Comment: what version of IIS on both environments?

Comment: @ChrisHammond - 7.5 on local, 7.0 on dev server.

Comment: did you change the entries in the portal alias table to match localhost or whatever you are using instead of www

Comment: @JKing - Yes, I added a portal alias for the new server. I guess that is why the home page is working and not redirecting me to my local version.

Comment: I'm not sure then, what is the requested url of your sub page and what is the url of your local host home page.  Can you add them to the post VIA an edit.

Comment: @ChrisHammond, before I go through IT approval process to get IIS upgraded on our server, do you think this difference in versions might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: It likely isn't necessary to upgrade. There's a configuration problem somewhere. Could we web.config, could be IIS, hard to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Microsoft hotfix for certain IIS 7 or 7.5 handlers that enables extensionless urls:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Without the hotfix, you can set urlformat to "humanfriendly" in web config, and this will allow navigation to the admin, host & subpages, but not without url extensions. The hotfix allows DNN to use the "advanced" extensionless setting.

**Thanks to Joe at dnncreative and William at wesnetdesigns for helping me figure this one out.